Gráfico cortado al usar tabsetPanel en un flexdashboard usando el grid layout en r markdown
estoy intentando aprovechar el grid layout para hacer un flexdashboard usando r markdown. Pero me gustaría usar pestañas para poder incluir más de un gráfico en cada cuadrante. Usando tabsetPanel me acerco bastante a lo que quiero, pero los gráficos se cortan, creo que debido a que parte del espacio del cuadrante es ocupado por las pestañas. ¿Se puede corregir esto de alguna manera, tal vez usando css?
---
title: "Prueba Tabs"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
require(shinydashboard)
require(shiny)
require(plotly)
```

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Gráfico A

```{r}
plot_ly(data = cars, x = ~speed, y = ~dist, mode = "markers")
```


### Gráfico B 

```{r}

plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~hp, type = "scatter", mode = "markers")

```

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Gráfico C

```{r}

plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, color = ~Species, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')

```


### Gráfico D

```{r}

tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("Gráfico 1", {
    plot_ly(data = cars, x = ~speed, y = ~dist, mode = "markers")
  }),
  tabPanel("Gráfico 2", {
    plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, color = ~Species, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
  }),
  tabPanel("Gráfico 3", {
    plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~hp, type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
  })
)

```

Muchas gracias!
